# Recursion error when using post_save signal with Wagtail admin

Tags: django, wagtail

I have an `Order` model and an `OrderItem` model with an override of `save()` on `Order` and a `post_save` signal for `OrderItem` so that the `Order` total and status will be automatically updated upon saving an `OrderItem`.  I have set up a `wagtailhooks.py` file in which I've set up `ModelAdmin` for the `Order` model.  Note in the following model definitions that `ClusterableModel` and `ParentalKey` have to be used to cause `OrderItem`s to display properly under an `Order` in the Wagtail admin:

```
class Order(BaseModel, ClusterableModel):
...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.calculate_costs()
    self.set_status()
    super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel([
        FieldPanel('number'),
        ...,
    ]),
    InlinePanel('order_items', label="Order Items")
]


class OrderItem(BaseModel, Orderable):
order = ParentalKey('Order', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='order_items')
product = ParentalKey('Product', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
...

panels = [
    ...
]


# SIGNALS
@receiver(post_save, sender=OrderItem)
def update_order(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.order.save()
```

THE PROBLEM:  An order with it's associated order items will display fine when I try to edit it from the Wagtail admin, but when I try to SAVE from the Wagtail admin, I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error.  However, when I save the same order from the DJANGO admin, it saves fine.  If I disconnect the `post_save` signal on `OrderItem`, the Order then saves fine from the Wagtail admin too.  Is there any way to have the Wagtail admin successfully save an order with the `post_save` signal in place?

The trace (with first, second, and third recursing calls noted):

```
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _cache_controlled
            response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py in wrapper
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py in decorated_view
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py in edit_view
        return view_class.as_view(**kwargs)(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func
                return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func
                return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
            return self.form_valid(form) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py in form_valid
        instance = form.save() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/forms.py in save
            formset.save(commit=commit) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/forms.py in save
            manager.commit() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/fields.py in commit
                    original_manager.add(item, bulk=False) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in add
                        obj.save() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
                update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using, ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in send
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in <listcomp>
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars


FIRST CALL TO instance.order.save() from post_save signal

./store/models.py in update_order
    instance.order.save() ...
▶ Local vars
./store/models.py in save
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/models.py in save
            getattr(self, relation).commit() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/fields.py in commit
                    original_manager.add(item, bulk=False) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in add
                        obj.save() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
                update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using, ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in send
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in <listcomp>
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars


SECOND CALL TO instance.order.save() from post_save signal

    instance.order.save() ...
▶ Local vars
./store/models.py in save
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/models.py in save
            getattr(self, relation).commit() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modelcluster/fields.py in commit
                    original_manager.add(item, bulk=False) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in add
                        obj.save() ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
                update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using, ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in send
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars
/opt/virtualenvs/KKF-1Oq8ncY2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py in <listcomp>
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender) ...
▶ Local vars


THIRD CALL TO instance.order.save() from post_save signal

./store/models.py in update_order
    instance.order.save() ...
▶ Local vars
./store/models.py in save
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Looks to me a trigger results in the same trigger.

Comment: Is it possible that the `Order` triggers the `OrderItem`s to save?

Comment: No, I don't have a `post_save` signal on `Order` that is triggering `OrderItem` to be saved.  I'm attaching the trace with the first and second (recursing) calls to `instance.order.save()` noted.

Comment: As background to why this happens - the whole purpose of `ClusterableModel` and `ParentalKey` is to treat the parent and child models as a single unit, so that child models (OrderItem in this case) are saved whenever the parent (Order) is. I can't see an obvious way of making this behaviour work alongside the signal, unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks @gasman.  You've confirmed my suspicion of what was causing the problem.   Maybe this could be handled by first checking for the existence of the parent, then do an explicit save if it doesn't exist (without executing any parent `save()` function) in order to establish the parent's pk, and then, after saving the child, run the parent's `save()` function (if one exists).  That said, such an approach might introduce other problems if a `save()` override was executed in this manner.  The only other way would be to execute any overridden `save()` twice.  Wish this problem could be solved.

Comment: update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save()). Maybe you can use update in your signals. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: I tried `update()`, but it only works on a queryset and I'd rather not convert a single object to a queryset.

Comment: You could also not use signals, just put everything in custom save methods.

Comment: Note that save() and `Foo.objects.filer(pk=1).update(...)` both hit the db just one time. I guess this is a valid workaround to your recursion problem.